# Creating a child-theme: CSS not loading

Tags: themes, child-theme

I created a custom theme (style.css in the dashboard)

```
/*
Theme Name:     Client customisations
Description:    Child theme for the client Website
Author:         Me
Author URI:     http://example.com/about/
Template:       aries
Version:        1.0.0
*/

@import url("../aries/style.css");

h2{
    color: #4E8B4E !important;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

When I visit the front page in Chrome, I see that `wp-content/themes/aries` was loaded, but not my custom theme that is currently activated. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: You may need to [enqueue the CSS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) as well.

Comment: @Jono: So it isn't loaded automatically?

Comment: I thought it was, but I'm guessing in your case it hasn't been, have you viewed the source of the page to see if you CSS is in the head?

Comment: @Jono: It isn't

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to replace `get_template_directory_uri()` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` in the parent template. I tried enqueing the css first, as I didn't want to modify the parent, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Actually, if you're referring to the primary stylesheet link, you should be using [**`get_stylesheet_uri()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri).

Comment: In which file was this string found?

Answer (score 0):

For future people, I found this thread and followed Casebash's advice:

Find the child-theme's functions.php and replace `get_template_directory_uri()` on the parent-style with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` so it looks like the following:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));
}
```

This worked for me immediately. I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Can you contribute what the correct solution would be?